# MySQL or PHP fault? IPV6

Tags: php, mysql, networking, ipv6

I have this configuration:
MySQL: 5.1.66-0+squeeze1-log,
PHP:  5.3.3-7+squeeze15,

I'm working wtih ipv6 address `2001:35c::/40`

While I'm manipulating it on php( inet_pton, inet_ntop) it is good, but after I put it into MySQL database (VARBINARY(16) field, it get messed up (`200103000000000000000000000000` instead of 2001035c0000000000000000000000). Where could be the problem?

```
$addr = '2001:35c::/40';

$addr = explode('/', $addr);
$address = $addr[0];

$address = inet_ntop(inet_pton($address));

$sql = "INSERT INTO IPv6 (IP, Mask, Parent_ID) VALUES ('".inet_pton($address)."', '".$addr[1]."', 0)";
$DB=new Database();
$DB->query($sql);
```

Also i spotted, that where there are `35c` parti in address (ipv6) it get messed up after inserting into MySQL

Comment: Are you sure that after this `$address = inet_ntop(inet_pton($address));` the `$address == '2001:35c::/40'`?

Comment: `$addr = '2001:35c::/40';
$addr = explode('/', $addr);
$addr[0] = inet_ntop(inet_pton($addr[0]));
$addr = implode('/', $addr);
echo $addr;` result: '2001:35c::/40'

Comment: What I don't get is you're converting it 3 times back and forth o_o ?

Comment: Also from the docs "This function converts a human readable IPv4 or IPv6 address **(if PHP was built with IPv6 support enabled)** into an address family appropriate 32bit or 128bit binary structure."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try quoting your data before inserting.

**MySQL**:

```
mysql_real_escape_string(inet_pton($address))
```

**PDO**:

```
$db->quote(inet_pton($address))
```

This methods also escape binary data, 0 becomes \0, etc.

@hamza-dzcyberdev I guess the triple converting is to get the shortest IPv6 notation. 0000:0000 could be shortened to ::, 0000: to 0: which in this case doesn't mind, but might in other situations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of quoting with `'` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` or `quote()`, you can also use `0x` so that the query looks like

```
INSERT INTO IPv6 (IP, Mask, Parent_ID) VALUES (0x2001035c0000000000000000000000, 40, 0).
```

I am not sure, however, how to handle this in PHP. Maybe (but not guaranteed!) this way:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO IPv6 (IP, Mask, Parent_ID) VALUES (0x".bin2hex($address).", '".$addr[1]."', 0)";
```

Depending on where `$addr` comes from, `$addr[1]` must be quoted as well.